# Creating Toolbox for ArcGIS that calculates route for maximum of 6 given addresses?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, network-analyst, arctoolbox

I like to build a Toolbox for the ArcGIS Network Analyst that takes a network and given addresses of a shapefile to calculate the best route.

Right now I am using the network-data of the [ArcGIS Network Analyst extension tutorial][1].

I have a shapefile with 1000 addresses, but I want to limit one route at one calculation with a **maximum of 6 addresses**.

Do I have to extract the addresses from the shapefile first before using the "Solve"-Tool or is there a better way?

In the end, I would like create an ArcGIS-Toolbox to have the possibility to choose the addresses with a drop-down menu for various address-lists and networks.

Right now I have the output of the Model Builder, `Stores` are my Addresses:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Python.py
# Created on: 2017-02-16 10:11:54.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: Python <Routes> 
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Routes = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Routes == '#' or not Routes:
    Routes = "Route1\\Routes" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Streets_ND = "F:\\Streets_ND"
Route1 = "Route1"
Route1__3_ = Route1
Pizzaladen = "Pizzaladen"
Route1__4_ = Route1__3_
Stores = "F:\\Stores"
Routes__3_ = Stores
Route__3_ = Route1__4_
Solve_Succeeded = "true"
output5_shp = "F:\\output5.shp"

# Process: Make Route Layer
arcpy.MakeRouteLayer_na(Streets_ND, "Route1", "TravelTime", "FIND_BEST_ORDER", "PRESERVE_BOTH", "USE_TIMEWINDOWS", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "Oneway;RestrictedTurns", "USE_HIERARCHY", "", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "")

# Process: Add Locations (2)
arcpy.AddLocations_na(Route1, "Stops", Pizzaladen, "", "5000 Meters", "", "Streets SHAPE;Streets_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "INCLUDE", "Streets #;Streets_ND_Junctions #")

# Process: Add Locations
arcpy.AddLocations_na(Route1__3_, "Stops", Stores, "Name Name #;Attr_Minutes ServiceTime 0", "5000 Meters", "", "Streets SHAPE;Streets_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "INCLUDE", "Streets #;Streets_ND_Junctions #")

# Process: Solve
arcpy.Solve_na(Route1__4_, "SKIP", "TERMINATE", "")

# Process: Select Data
arcpy.SelectData_management(Route__3_, "Routes")

# Process: Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Routes, output5_shp, "", "0", "0", "0")

# Process: Select Data (2)
arcpy.SelectData_management(Stores, "Routes")
```

**Is it possible to make a selection of 6 `Stores`/addresses among these Tools?**

Comment: All geoprocessing tools honour selections so it may be as simple as having the points selected before you run the solve tool?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include detail about what you've tried, and what happens when you try it.  Are you trying to create a python toolbox or script tool to do this?  Include any code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extract files with the Select(Analysis) tool. For the start of my route is determinded, I started my 'where_clause' (-->`Expression`) with a fixed address.

```
#Input
Addresses = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#Output
Select_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

Expression = "Name = 'Address_22'" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)+ arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)+ arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)+ arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)

# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(Addresses, Select_shp, Expression)
```

See this [help topic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000n000000) for more information on the script tool parameters that I used in the script properties.

Now, I have a dropdown-menue to choose of the adresses I defined before and am able to extract the shapefiles as I wanted.

Comment: there is an even more elegant way [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229161/multivalue-string-to-sql-expressions)